# Is $ f $ is constant with respect to $ w $?

Tags: real-analysis

Let be $ f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R} $ differentiable with $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (a,b) $ for all $ (a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2. $ Now define $ z:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2, (v,w)\mapsto (v+w,v-w) $.

How can I show that $ \frac{\partial (f\circ z)}{\partial w}(v+w,v-w)=0 $?

Comment: Apply Chain Rule.

Comment: I know I have to apply the chain rule but I don't know how.

Comment: Chain rule is:

$$
\frac{\partial(f\circ g)}{\partial w} = \sum_\ell \partial_w g_\ell \times (\partial_\ell f)\circ g
$$

Comment: I don't know this formular. What is $ \times $ ?

Comment: I only know this formular: $ \frac{\partial (g\circ h)_i}{\partial t_j}(t)=\sum\limits_{l=1}^n \frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_l}(h(t))\cdot \frac{\partial h_l}{\partial t_j}(t)$. I don't know how to plug all things in here. What is $ x_l $ here?

Answer (score 0):

$F(u,w) = f(z(u,w)) = f(z_1(u,w),z_2(u,w))$

The chain rule says $\frac{\partial F}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial f }{\partial x } \frac{dz_1 }{d u}+\frac{\partial f }{\partial y} \frac{dz_2 }{d u}$.

The terms $\frac{dz_1 }{d u}$ and $\frac{dz_2 }{d u}$ can be computed since you are given $z_1$ and $z_2$.

The terms $\frac{\partial f }{\partial x }$ and $\frac{\partial f }{\partial y}$ cannot be simplified but you can relate them using the information given.

This is enough to show $\frac{\partial F}{\partial u} =0$.